# How to query influxdb within grafana dashboard to create a template variable

Tags: load, influxdb, telegraf, grafana-templating

I am collecting metrics using [telegraf](https://www.influxdata.com/time-series-platform/telegraf/) and the [system plugin](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/blob/master/plugins/inputs/system/SYSTEM_README.md) on influxdb, I am trying to create some [singlestats pannels](http://docs.grafana.org/features/panels/singlestat/) to measure the **load average** on multiple instances with accurate "warnings"

For doing this I need to create a template variable with the number of existing CPUs based on the selected `$host` in the gauge meter and coloring thresholds options:

```
SHOW TAG VALUES WITH KEY=host
```

The dashboard should return only information from the selected host, therefore, I need to dynamically configure the Gauge values `max` and coloring thresholds so that the colors could change for example to red when the load is matching the `number of cores - 1`.

Currently, I am hardcoding the values in `max = 4` and in the Coloring threshold using `1,3` that is `ncpus -1`. (this works only for instances having 4 cores, but not for instances having less or more than 4)

[image]

My try to create a variable named `$ncpus` is this:

```
> SELECT last("n_cpus") FROM "system" WHERE ("host" =~ /^my-host$/) 
name: system
time                last
----                ----
1526379330000000000 4
```

I want to get the `4` but I am getting the `time`, this is what I am using currently:

[image]

Any idea about how to get only the number of cpus `n_cpus` so that could be stored in a variable removing the `time` and also been available to use it in the `singlestat` options?

Comment: Load value can be more than number of CPUs. Especially if you have modern fast CPU and old slow storage. Really, there is no upper limit for that value. Also is load normalization by using number of CPUs is not correct. It should be number of online CPUs.

Answer (score 1):

You should write a query similar to the following

`SHOW TAG VALUES ON "DATABASE_NAME" FROM "elasticsearch_cluster_health" WITH KEY = "name"`

[image]